# FFmpeg command help and pointers for documentation

Tags: java, android, c, video, ffmpeg

I was working with FFmpeg for one of my android project. So far, I have been able to successfully able to compile FFmpeg for ARM. Now my approach is to write a JNI interface for playing videos using FFmpeg.

I tried executing the command `./ffmpeg --help` to see the options available with FFmpeg, and so far I am only able to understand that the input filename can be provided with `-i fileName` option.

I have been searching for online tutorials / blogs for FFmpeg commands, and how to play a video / RTMP stream, but couldn't find a suitable link.

I'd like to know the following:

1. What is the command to play a video using FFMpeg?
2. What is the command to play a local file using FFMpeg
3. What is the command to play a RTMP stream using FFMpeg
4. Java / C sample code to play video using FFMpeg
5. Is it possible to extract some piece of code from `ffplay.c` and write a custom code?

Any help with the above and / or any pointers to relevant links is highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: For the record, it is FFmpeg...not FFMpeg.  (No big M.)  But good on you for the effort.

Comment: Thanks Stu for that indicator.. :-)

Answer (score 2):

The `ffmpeg` command, part of FFmpeg project, is 'just' the encoder.  It sounds like you are looking for `ffplay`, and the documentation can be found here: [ffmpeg.org/ffplay.html](http://ffmpeg.org/ffplay.html).  Note that a build of FFmpeg can also have other executable binaries, like `ffserver`.  You may need to explicately enable ffplay when running `./configure`

Good luck.  I've never heard of anyone using ffplay before.  I don't believe it is a common way to play videos an any device, let alone a mobile.

Comment: Thanks for the link and the clarification. You helped me by making my understanding more clear i.e. `FFmpeg` (small 'm' :-) ) is an encoder and not a player. That's a real basic. I'll go through the link. Thanks again.

Comment: I tried to enable the build for `ffplay`. I saw the output of `ffmpeg --help`, but it only showed option for `--disable-ffplay`. I assumed that a similar `--enable-ffplay` should work, but when the build completed, I didn't find a binary for `ffplay` inside the `bin` directory... Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: @mahi: No idea.  Maybe track down the ffplay.c file and try to compile directly.  But you probably should find another way to play video.  I found something that says *"It is mostly used as a testbed for the various FFmpeg APIs."*  http://linux.die.net/man/1/ffplay